# find multiple elements in one loop for python

Tags: python

I have to insert a few XML tags into the SQL database.
I am able to get values by the below code. But I have to insert multiple values like created, comments, name, modify, etc. How can I get all in one call and insert it in one statement into SQL?

```
for element in root.iter('Created'):
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML document?

Comment: can you post the expected SQL statement together with the XML document? Are you using plain SQL or ORM's (like SQLAlchemy)?

Comment: Not sure to share the XML .. here is the schema.

Comment: <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="No" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>

Comment: Don't place long code in comments

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

With [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```py
tags = ['Created', 'Comments', 'Name', 'Modify']
tag_iterators = [root.iter(tag) for tag in tags]
for element in itertools.chain(*tag_iterators):
    print(element.text)
```

With iterating through all tags and then filtering:

```py
tags = ['Created', 'Comments', 'Name', 'Modify']
for element in root.iter():
    if element.tag not in tags:
        continue
    print(element.text)
```

Finally, if you need all the tags, then simply:

```py
for element in root.iter():
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, gnvk !.  I was looking for exactly this thing only.

Comment: one quick question- how can I concatenate (element.text) into one string in for element in root.iter(): case.

Comment: Probably with the + operator. But there isn't enough context to answer this properly, you should either figure it out with the help of other questions or open a new one with the details.

Comment: Hi gnvk, I have now multiple tags with the same name. I want only first-time tag to be appended not next time